# Select(highlight) all elements with the same class. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to user select (highlight) all the text content of some class

I tried doing

```
range = document.createRange()
for (var i = selectionItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   range.selectNode(selectionItems[i])
}
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
window.getSelection().addRange(range)
```

However, this code ends up reassigning range instead of stacking selected nodes.
This seems to have an easy solution, however, I was not able to find anything on the selection documentation page. Would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Actually the **window.getSelection() is browser specific**, in Chrome it accepts only one range, but in FireFox the ranges get appended.

try below code in both chrome and firefox

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="classA">1. This is a text with classA</p>
    <p class="classB">2. This is a text with classB</p>
    <p class="classA">3. This is a text with classA</p>
    <p class="classA">4. This is a text with classA</p>
    <p class="classC">5. This is a text with classC</p>
    <p class="classA">6. This is a text with classA</p>

    <button>Select Class A</button>
    <script>
      let button = document.querySelector('button');
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('click');
        let selection = window.getSelection();
        let classRef = document.getElementsByClassName('classA');

        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
          selection.removeAllRanges();
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < classRef.length; i++) {
          let range = document.createRange();
          range.selectNode(classRef[i]);
          console.log(range)
          selection.addRange(range);
          console.log(selection.rangeCount);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if you still need the same functionality a bit hard way. Then

1. Use the background styles to select all the same class for the client to see.
2. Use window.getSelection() for each nodes with same class, and then copy to an external variable as string or array.

Comment: Any ideas on a solution that can be applied to Chrome as well? (Without CSS)

Comment: @Vagif Sorry, no idea about other ways, except with using CSS classes